# required a bean of type that could not be found when register and autowired using the child class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have met quite a strange situation, while compiling im my develope and test environment then run my application, it is OK. But when I deploy my code to production environment the code was crashed although compiling was a succeed.

The error is
`required a bean of type xxxxxxx that could not be found`

The dependencies are all OK, and the application was run well in all my dev and test servers except for prod server.

Here is the simplified project structure:

myproject
    |
    module-common
    |       |
    |       com.myapp.config
    |           |
    |           GlobalSnowFlakeConfig.java
    module-application(dependent on module-common)
           |
           Application.java (springboot main function)
           
com.myapp.config
           |    |
           |    CustomizedSnowFlakeConfig.java
           com.myapp.service
               |
               TargetService.java

Here is the code:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class GlobalSnowFlakeConfig {
    @Value("${spring.application.name:anonymous}")
    private String applicationName;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private String port;


    @Bean
    public MachineInfo registerMachineInfo(RedissonUtil redissonUtil, RedisUtils redisUtils) {
        log.info("Loading MachineInfo...");
        return new MachineInfo(redissonUtil, redisUtils, applicationName, port);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Snowflake.class)
    public Snowflake initializeSnowFlake(MachineInfo machineInfo) {
        log.info("Current DataCenterId={} machineId={}", machineInfo.getDataCenterId(), machineInfo.getMachineId());
        return new Snowflake(
                machineInfo.getMachineId(),
                machineInfo.getDataCenterId(),
                true);
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomizedSnowFlake extends Snowflake {
    ....the overriding methods and new features....
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class CustomizedSnowFlakeConfig {
    @Bean
    public Snowflake initializeSnowFlake(MachineInfo machineInfo) {
        log.info("Current DataCenterId={} machineId={}", machineInfo.getDataCenterId(), machineInfo.getMachineId());
        return new CustomizedSnowFlake(
                machineInfo.getMachineId(),
                machineInfo.getDataCenterId(),
                true,
                machineInfo.getIp() + ":" + machineInfo.getPort());
    }
}
```

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketServiceImpl{
    @Autowired
    private CustomizedSnowFlake snowflake;

    ....other business code....
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp"})
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.myapp.webcommon.api"})
@MapperScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.mydb.mapper"})
public class Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        WebSocketServer.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

I think method `initializeSnowFlake` will override the config of `Snowflake` and replace the `GlobalSnowFlakeConfig`'s bean of type `Snowflake`, but the jar file compliled in my prod server can never start up, it will always print `required a bean of type xxxx.CustomizedSnowFlake that could not be found`.

On the other hand, all the same code compiled in my dev and test server has nothing wrong and good to start.

I have checked my maven and jdk version, There are little differences :

```
In prod server

Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_291, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_291/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.23-5.al8.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

```
In test server1

Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: /etc/maven/apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"


IN test server2

Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: Red Hat, Inc., runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.292.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Although application can be started well by changing return type from `Snowflake` to `CustomizedSnowflake` in `CustomizedSnowFlakeConfig`, I still don't know why my test and dev environment never come up with this problem.

the version of maven and jdk in `test server1` and `prod server` are nearly the same. So I don't think this problem is due to maven version or jdk version.

By debugging into source code of springboot, I have found someting strange.

in `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry`, method `isTypeMatch` will call `getSingleton` to get the singletonObject named `initializeSnowFlake` which is defined in `CustomizedSnowFlakeConfig`, but the jar file compiled in prod server will never have such object returned while the jar file compiled in test/dev server will have one.
[image]

I don't know why such singletonObject is not in `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry`,everything looks normal.

Comment: have you tried to replace `@Bean public Snowflake initializeSnowFlake`  with `@Bean public CustomizedSnowFlake initializeSnowFlake`?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks a lot! The problem solved by register a bean with type CustomizedSnowFlake!

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov But I still don't know the reason that leads to this kind of problem ...

Comment: frankly speaking I have no idea why does the previous setup work, in my projects I see that `spring` typically can't infer real bean type from `@Bean` method.

Comment: Yes, while debugging in jar file compiled by prod server, Spring can't infer real bean type, and line `return typeToMatch.isAssignableFrom(beanType)` in `AbstractBeanFactory`'s `protected boolean isTypeMatch(String name, ResolvableType typeToMatch, boolean allowFactoryBeanInit)` method will always return false. And the jar file compiled by test server will not have such problem due to a totally different bean instanciate order, such bean can be reached when doing the same thing...

Comment: UB caused by different initialization order is a disaster, for that reason we do not use constructor DI and `@Lazy` annotations, we newer interact with infrastructure in constructors or factory methods (unlike some spring components) and prefer to use `SmartLifecycle`. Now, thanks to your Q and investigation, I'm aware of another one "initialization order" case.